# Mulesoft - Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.7: Could not transfer artifact

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am setting up an existing mule application but running into below error. any help please..

[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7 or

one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.7:

Could not transfer artifact org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:pom:1.7 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/):

Blocked mirror for repositories: [mulesoft-release (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/, default, releases)] -> [Help 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Mirrors on settings file resolved the issue.

Found the solution from below post

[How to disable maven blocking external HTTP repositores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001968/how-to-disable-maven-blocking-external-http-repositores)

```
<mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>my-repository-http-unblocker1</id>
          <mirrorOf>mulesoft-release</mirrorOf>
          <name></name>
          <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>;
          <blocked>false</blocked>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
          <id>jfrog-http-unblocker1</id>
          <mirrorOf>jfrog</mirrorOf>
          <name></name>
          <url>http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/plugins-releases-local</url>;
          <blocked>false</blocked>
        </mirror>   
  </mirrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your pom.xml or settings.xml is referencing one of the MuleSoft Maven Repositories using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Try changing all URL to use `https://...`. You can see the recommended configurations in the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb