# WSO2 and VSCODE build .car file fail

Tags: wso2

I want to switch from Integration stuido to VSCode, I followed the tutorial, installed java 11 and maeven 3.8, created a simple Proxy then run the command "wso2ei:Build integration project" here is the problem I get :
Can you tell me the procedure?
1000 thanks in advance

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.wso2.maven:vscode-car-plugin:5.2.29 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.wso2.maven:vscode-car-plugin:jar:5.2.29 -> org.wso2.maven:org.wso2.maven.core:jar:5.2.29 -> org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2:axiom:jar:1.2.11.wso2v4 @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: car @ line 24, column 16
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.test.esb:com.test.esb.project:1.0-SNAPSHOT (c:\Users\Shadow\Documents\2023-VS-WSO2\TestEsbProjectV0.75\com.test.esb.project\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.wso2.maven:vscode-car-plugin:5.2.29 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.wso2.maven:vscode-car-plugin:jar:5.2.29 -> org.wso2.maven:org.wso2.maven.core:jar:5.2.29 -> org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2:axiom:jar:1.2.11.wso2v4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2:axiom:jar:1.2.11.wso2v4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2:axiom:pom:1.2.11.wso2v4 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [wso2.releases (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/, default, releases+snapshots), wso2.snapshots (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/, default, snapshots), wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: car @ line 24, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

I tried to modify the pom.xml file
find the vscode.car.plugin
try with the last version 5.2.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in your pom.xml files, addresses of repositories and pluginRepositories url from `http://...` to `https://...`
From version 3.8.1 maven blocks external HTTP repositories by default.  What is showing like that:

`maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) ...`

And some other workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002852/2760506