# Facing error in building maven project after configuring /root/.m2/setting.xml for JFrog OSS

Tags: maven, open-source, jfrog-insights

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.3.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:3.3.0 (present, but unavailable): Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:3.3.0 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [central (http://13.127.219.37:8081/artifactory/libs-release, default, releases), snapshots (http://13.127.219.37:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot, default, releases+snapshots)]

I wanted to build a maven project and then deploy to JFrog snapshot repository.

Comment: "maven-default-http-blocker" seems to be the key here. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002852/1820778