# Maven can't find dependencies for talend ci builder

Tags: maven, azure-devops, continuous-integration, pom.xml, talend

In my Azure DevOps pipeline I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:7.3.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:jar:7.3.4: Could not transfer artifact org.talend.ci:builder-maven-plugin:pom:7.3.4 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [plugins_snapshot (http://XXX.stratoserver.net:XXX/repository/talend-custom-libs-snapshot/, default, releases+snapshots), plugins_release (http://XXX.stratoserver.net:XXX/repository/talend-custom-libs-release/, default, releases+snapshots), central (http://XXX.stratoserver.net:XXX/repository/maven-central/, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I tried looking up the error with the provided link inside the error, but i can't manage to find what it is about.
Does anyone have any clue what could be wrong here? Obviously it says something about the ci builder plugin but i looked it up and it is inside my POM.

My POM:

```
<properties>
    <signer.version>7.3.1</signer.version>
    <talend.project.name>DATAOPS</talend.project.name>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
    <talend.docker.tag>${project.version}</talend.docker.tag>
    <talend.docker.name>${talend.project.name.lowercase}/${talend.job.folder}%a</talend.docker.name>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
              <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
              <version>1.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
              <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.24</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
              <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.24</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
              <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.24</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
              <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.24</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
              <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.24</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
              <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.24</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
              <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.24</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.talend.ci</groupId>
        <artifactId>builder-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>docker</id>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
              <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>4.0.0</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>0.29.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                  <version>2.10.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                  <version>2.10.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                  <version>2.10.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
                  <version>2.10.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
                  <version>2.10.1</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>start</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>build</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>push-image</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>push</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <skip>${docker.skip}</skip>
              <autoPull>once</autoPull>
              <images>
                <image>
                  <name>${talend.docker.name}</name>
                  <build>
                    <from>openjdk:8-jre-slim</from>
                    <tags>
                      <tag>${talend.docker.tag}</tag>
                    </tags>
                    <env>
                      <JAVA_OPTS>${talend.job.jvmargs}</JAVA_OPTS>
                    </env>
                    <runCmds>
                      <run>chmod +x /maven/${talend.job.name}/${talend.job.name}_run.sh</run>
                      <run>sed -i 's/ -Xms[0-9]*M//g' /maven/${talend.job.name}/${talend.job.name}_run.sh</run>
                      <run>sed -i 's/-Xmx[0-9]*M/$JAVA_OPTS/g' /maven/${talend.job.name}/${talend.job.name}_run.sh</run>
                    </runCmds>
                    <workdir>/maven/${talend.job.name}</workdir>
                    <entryPoint>
                      <exec>
                        <arg>./${talend.job.name}_run.sh</arg>
                      </exec>
                    </entryPoint>
                    <assembly>
                      <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assemblies/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </assembly>
                  </build>
                </image>
              </images>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>cloud-publisher</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.talend.ci</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudpublisher-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>publish</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <skip>${cloud.publisher.skip}</skip>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <maven.deploy.skip>false</maven.deploy.skip>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Any help is much appreciated, and if any extra information is needed please tell me!

Comment: You could try to run`mvn clean install` before the mvn task. If it couldn't work, you could share the task definition with us.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has upgraded maven recently from 3.6.3 to 3.8.1.

Starting from this maven build, http repositories are by default blocked.

Best solution is to upgrade to https.

Another solution would be to create an exception, and allow http.
More information about this, you can find in the answer on this question :
[Maven Build Failure — DependencyResolutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980047/maven-build-failure-dependencyresolutionexception)