# How to compile Vaadin 8 application since it's been discontinued

Tags: vaadin

I suspect this is related to Vaadin 8 recently being discontinued. I'm trying to run a Vaadin 8 reference application as part of an upgrade effort to Vaadin Flow and today it's starting to give me maven compile errors that the dependencies are no longer available for Vaadin 8. For example I got the error  "Failed to collect dependencies at com.vaadin:vaadin-charts" and so on with the details of the version. This is also happening for all Vaadin 8 dependencies, including all Vaadin 8 addons libraries. I need to run the reference application in my IDE but cannot find any way to do so.

Comment: Vaadin 8 dependencies should be available as before. And BTW, Vaadin 8 is still supported (for ten years), but upcoming versions will be under commercial license. Can you share the full build log and maybe snippets of your pom.xml?

Comment: Yesterday there where a lot of vaadin server timeouts, probably this causing problems retrieving the dependencies

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm still getting errors today.  The [###] are my comments. Here's an example error: Failed to collect dependencies at com.vaadin:[###jar name]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:[###jar and version] Could not transfer artifact com.vaadin:vaadin-charts:pom:[###version] from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [vaadin-addons (http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons, default, releases+snapshots)

Comment: Blocked mirror for repositories: This indicates that maven has blocked using the repository. This can happen when using Maven 3.8, which prevents access to repositories using the http protocol (rather than https) for example. Maybe give it a try with Maven 3.6, which does not have the blocking feature. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833372/getting-blocked-mirror-for-repositories-maven-error-even-after-adding-mirrors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last free public release of Vaadin 8 is version 8.14.3. The release is in maven central is not going to be removed. So it remains to be usable.

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm still getting errors today.  The [###] are my comments. Here's an example error: Failed to collect dependencies at com.vaadin:[###jar name]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vaadin:[###jar and version] Could not transfer artifact com.vaadin:vaadin-charts:pom:[###version] from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [vaadin-addons (http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons, default, releases+snapshots)

Comment: The issue was due to using http vs https for the add-on repository. However when I changed that I'm still having a charts issues in that it no longer recognizes the class com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.style.SolidColor. Any ideas...

Comment: It seems to only happen with Maven 3.8.1+ and not 3.6.3. With or without https. Any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was a combination of upgrading to Maven 3.8.1 (through an Intellij upgrade) as well as an older `pom.xml` using `http` for the vaadin addons library from version 8. To correct it I had to change the following in my `pom.xml`:

```
<repository>
    <id>vaadin-addons</id>
    <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

Specifically notice the `<url>` has `https` rather than `http`.

That being said I still have a remaining issue with Vaadin charts that no longer recognizes the class `com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.style.SolidColor`

The only working solution was to revert to Maven 3.6.3 as I could not make fully resolve it with Maven 3.8.1 even with the https change.

Comment: Actually that repository is not Vaadin 8 specific, but serves all Vaadin add-ons published in Directory

Comment: I had some weird maven issues which got very confusing and only seemed to affect Vaadin. It was all related to the http vs https setup in the pom. Took a while to figure out. Thanks for the help.