# Unable include the lib and its dependencies in a Maven project for https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am trying to include this git hub repo in my maven project. I have added the following things to my pom.xml per the read me.

```
<repository>
     <id>GeoSolutions</id>
     <url>http://maven.geo-solutions.it/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>it.geosolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoserver-manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However when doing a clean install I am getting this error

Could not resolve dependencies for project Failed to collect dependencies at it.geosolutions:geoserver-manager:jar:1.7.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for it.geosolutions:geoserver-manager:jar:1.7.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: it.geosolutions:geoserver-manager:pom:1.7.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact it.geosolutions:geoserver-manager:pom:1.7.0 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [GeoSolutions (http://maven.geo-solutions.it/, default, releases+snapshots)]

I expected to be able to use this in my project

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833372/getting-blocked-mirror-for-repositories-maven-error-even-after-adding-mirrors

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your setting.xml:

```
<mirror>
<id>GeoSolutions</id>
<url>http://maven.geo-solutions.it</url>
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

I also had the same problem too,and I just solved it.You can try if this method works for you.