# vaadin Add On csvalidation Failed to collect dependencies

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to understand how Add On on Vaadin works;
So in the following link:

https://github.com/magi42/csvalidation

There is written that to see an example is enough to

```
$ git clone https://github.com/magi42/csvalidation
$ mvn clean install
$ cd demo
$ mvn jetty:run
```

But I get:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project csvalidation-demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.vaadin.addons:csvalidation-demo:war:0.5.5: Failed to collect dependencies at org.vaadin.addons:csvalidation:jar:0.5.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.vaadin.addons:csvalidation:jar:0.5.5: Could not transfer artifact org.vaadin.addons:csvalidation:pom:0.5.5 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [vaadin-addons (http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

There is something wrong!!!!
But I cannot figure out what.

Comment: If you are new to Vaadin you probably want to use at least Vaadin 14 (current LTS) or Vaadin 22 which is latest release. Next is 23 LTS version.

The addon you are referring to is made to work with Vaadin 7. The plugin itself is very old. About 6 years. Are you sure that this is what you want to continue with?

I would recommend you to play with Vaadin 14 and look for addons here https://vaadin.com/directory and only focus on addons supporting Vaadin 14. In near future there will be many addons also supporting Vaadin 23 LTS.

Comment: no unfortunately I have to work with Vaadin 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was on the newest version of maven that not allow to download if the repository is not the "standard"; in settings.xml change from:

```
 <mirror>
      <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
       <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf> 
      <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
      <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
      <blocked>true</blocked>
    </mirror>
```

to

```
 <mirror>
            <id>releases-java-net-http-unblocker</id>
            <mirrorOf>releases.java.net</mirrorOf>
            <name>releases.java.net</name>
            <url>http://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <blocked>false</blocked>
        </mirror>
```

and it works!!!
as indicated in
[Maven Build Failure -- DependencyResolutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980047/maven-build-failure-dependencyresolutionexception)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the artifact id in your pom.xml to just csvalidation, instead of csvalidation-demo.

Comment: I did it doesn't work