# Vaadin project failed to start because IllegalStateException caused by Tomcat webserver

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I try to implement a simple Vaadin application from here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/

Anyone could help me please?

Thanks

---

I have got this:

```
    2022-04-04 11:32:37.547  INFO 16795 --- [           main] c.e.demo.CrudWithVaadinApplication       : Starting CrudWithVaadinApplication using Java 11.0.14.1 on Zsolts-AppRadar-MacBook.local with PID 16795 (/Users/zsoltgaramszegi/IdeaProjects/PRACTISE/vaadin_demo/target/classes started by zsoltgaramszegi in /Users/zsoltgaramszegi/IdeaProjects/PRACTISE/vaadin_demo)
2022-04-04 11:32:37.549  INFO 16795 --- [           main] c.e.demo.CrudWithVaadinApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-04-04 11:32:37.884  INFO 16795 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-04-04 11:32:37.910  INFO 16795 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-04-04 11:32:38.187  INFO 16795 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-04-04 11:32:38.193  INFO 16795 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-04-04 11:32:38.193  INFO 16795 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-04-04 11:32:38.262  INFO 16795 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-04-04 11:32:38.263  INFO 16795 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 689 ms
2022-04-04 11:32:38.946  INFO 16795 --- [           main] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for subclasses and classes with annotations took 0 seconds
2022-04-04 11:32:38.947  INFO 16795 --- [           main] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Due to slow search it is recommended to use the whitelisted-packages feature to make scanning faster.

See the whitelisted-packages section in the docs at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/spring/configuration#special-configuration-parameters
2022-04-04 11:32:38.948  INFO 16795 --- [           main] c.v.f.server.startup.DevModeInitializer  : Starting dev-mode updaters in /Users/zsoltgaramszegi/IdeaProjects/PRACTISE/vaadin_demo folder.
2022-04-04 11:32:38.964  INFO 16795 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Visited 91 classes. Took 11 ms.
2022-04-04 11:32:38.988  INFO 16795 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Running `npm install` to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2022-04-04 11:32:39.001 ERROR 16795 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Error when running `npm install`

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "--no-update-notifier" (in directory "/Users/zsoltgaramszegi/IdeaProjects/PRACTISE/vaadin_demo"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:365) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.execute(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:138) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:529) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:330) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:447) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.example.demo.CrudWithVaadinApplication.main(CrudWithVaadinApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107) ~[na:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted

2022-04-04 11:32:39.002 ERROR 16795 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize Vaadin DevModeHandler
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:450) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.example.demo.CrudWithVaadinApplication.main(CrudWithVaadinApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:341) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:447) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:409) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.execute(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:138) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:529) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:330) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "--no-update-notifier" (in directory "/Users/zsoltgaramszegi/IdeaProjects/PRACTISE/vaadin_demo"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:365) ~[flow-server-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107) ~[na:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted

2022-04-04 11:32:39.002 ERROR 16795 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-04-04 11:32:39.002 ERROR 16795 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-04-04 11:32:39.023  INFO 16795 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-04-04 11:32:39.025  WARN 16795 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-04-04 11:32:39.029  INFO 16795 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-04 11:32:39.038 ERROR 16795 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.example.demo.CrudWithVaadinApplication.main(CrudWithVaadinApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

---

My pom.xml:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.6.3
 

com.example
crud-with-vaadin-complete
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
crud-with-vaadin-complete
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>14.8.0</vaadin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tag::starter[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end::starter[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- tag::bom[] -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<!-- end::bom[] -->

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Does anything change if you upgrade Vaadin version from 14.8.0 to 14.8.6?

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but now I got this:
Could not transfer metadata org.webjars.npm:mobile-drag-drop/maven-metadata.xml from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): transfer failed for http://0.0.0.0/org/webjars/npm/mobile-drag-drop/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: That sounds like this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980047/maven-build-failure-dependencyresolutionexception. But I'm not sure why it's happening in this case.

Comment: Btw, there is a more up-to-date Vaadin CRUD guide here: https://foojay.io/today/create-a-crud-ui-in-pure-java/ in case you want to give it a try.

Comment: The "Could not transfer metadata org.webjars.npm..." is just a warning and can be solved excluding org.webjars.* from vaadin dependencies. That's because AFAIK webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode.